# How can I fix the smooth scroll function on my personal portfolio website using this CSS for the header?

Tags: css, scroll

My smooth scroll function doesn't seem to be working for my personal portfolio website, please check out the code below for my css for my header:`

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}
body{
    background: #080808;
    color: #fff;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(Images/Europe-png.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.container{
    padding: 10px 1%;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.logo{
    width: 160px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px 20px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #ff004f;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -6px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}
.header-text{
    margin-top: 20%;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(147, 139, 50);
}
.header-text h1{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.header-text h1 span{
    color: #ff004f
}
```

I tried adding the scroll-behavior to the body, and !important to the html. Both seem to have no fix... Do you guys have any experience with this issue? Any recommendations please?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it may be a browser issue. Have you tried another browser to see if that the issue persists there?

There are known issues with this on **MacOS Safari** as it does not support the attribute `scroll-behaviour: smooth`. You can check browser compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior)

### Update: Alternative Method

Using a javascript plugin from 'Chris Ferdinandi' which the GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll#getting-started)

As you're new to JavaScript and jQuery, I'd suggest that you include the Smooth-scroll plugin inside your `head` tag as a CDN with:

> `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll@15/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>`

Then, you will want to create another js file and include it alongside your CDN with another `<script>` tag.

> `<script> var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]'); </script>`

What this will do is ensure that any anchor tags you create that scroll to other elements will scroll smoothly. You can read up on the aforementioned [GitHub Documentation](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll#getting-started) on how to customise things such as the speed.

### Demo

```js
var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll@15/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<p id="top">
    <a href="#bazinga">Go to the middle</a><br>
    <a href="#1@#%^-bottom">Go to the bottom</a>
</p>

<p>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
</p>

<p id="bazinga"><a href="#1@#%^-bottom">Go to the bottom</a></p>

<p>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
</p>

<p id="1@#%^-bottom"><a href="#top">Go back to the top</a></p>
```

**Note**

This will not interfere with any tags that link to actual webpages.

Comment: Would JavaScript be easy to install???

Comment: Javascript is built in to almost all modern web browsers, there is no installation required. Just simply link a `<script>` tag to your html document in the `<head>` tag. and you can write your javascript document. W£Schools has some  excellent tutorials fro beginners on that. However, I will update the answer I have here soon to help you out.